# How to figure out what's consuming memory in my program?

Tags: java, performance, javafx

I am working on a project in java that appears to have a memory leak.

It starts using 300mb of memory, which strikes me as a lot, but wouldn't be absolutely surprising considering what the program is doing and its current level of optimization.

However, after a while of clicking around the UI and scrolling through each item on a table that has 2500 objects, the memory usage slowly climbs to around 926MB or higher, which doesn't seem reasonable.

[image]

The table has three columns, and about 2500 rows. That object has about 20 members, mostly primitives, a few Strings, and two files.

I dumped the heap using `jmap.exe -dump:format=b,file=output.bin 4088` and then loaded the heap into **Eclipse Memory Analyzer**.

The heap file itself is 757mb, while the memory use is reported to be 926mb, so that's a little surprising.

The big problem I'm facing is that either I don't know how to use the tool, or the tool isn't showing me all of the objects.

**The "Overview" analysis suggests a total size of 87.2MB**, which is an order of magnitude smaller than the dump file's size and the memory usage reported by windows:

[image]

**The "Histogram" analysis suggests the total size of the heap is ~91MB**:

[image]

**Similarly, the "Dominator Tree" view suggestions the heap to be about 90MB**:

[image]

So there are a handful of possibilities I see:

1. I have no idea what I'm doing *<==Very likely*
2. Windows is reporting the memory usage incorrectly
3. Eclipse Memory Analyzer isn't giving me the full picture from the heap -- the dump file is 757MB, but it's only telling me about ~90MB.
4. The memory that's getting consume isn't on the heap -- but where else could it be?
5. Something else entirely.

Any help for how to chase down this memory usage would be very appreciated!

Comment: The heap usage is different to the memory usage. It is likely that your program uses large amounts of memory in bursts - these bring the heap up to 1GB, then the GC kicks in and clears it out. The usage you see in Windows is the _maximum_ as Java will grab heap up to `-Xmx` and not give it back. You need to run with [JFR](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm#JFRUH164) to profile the application and see what causes these spikes.

Comment: `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,dumponexit=true,dumponexitpath=path` ought to do it - that will create a JFR file at `path` when the program exits. You can then use Java Mission Control (bundled with the JDK) to open the file and poke around.

Comment: Do the spikes matter in terms of system performance?  Will java give allocation back to windows if memory becomes a scarce resource? Seeing the large number in task manager is scary for me as a developer, and more importantly would turn me off to a piece of software as a user.  Is there a way to tell the JVM to give unused memory back occasionally?

Comment: Nope - sadly not; it won't have any detrimental impact on the program but, as you say, it will reduce the amount of memory available to other programs and may make users unhappy. You can try running with a smaller `-Xmx` to see if the program performs badly. Give it `300M`, then try and reduce it and profile to see how GC activity changes.